# How can i configure Regular expression extractor in jmeter while dynamic value for courseid value?

Tags: jmeter

**My scenario**
While course creation,dynamic course id value passing through manage course screen.
**Step1**:I have configure, Regular expression extractor for course creation http sampler 
[image] 
[image] 
**Step2**:Get this course id as parameter in manage course screen .But get the wrong course id as parameter.

[image]

Generated courseid is **1109** and In manage course screen, received course id is **2016**
  [image]
  [image]

```
    I need server generated course id(1109) in manage course screen.

    So,Kindly give me a solution for this scenario.

    Kindly refer this attachment.

    Thanks,Vairamuthu
```

Comment: You should Try <courseid="(.+?)"> in regular expression.
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Regular Expression Extractor` configuration should be like:

```
Reference name: AA
Regular Expression: courseid=(\d+)
Template: $1$
Match No.(0 For Random): 1
```

For Regex test see here: https://regex101.com/r/1xZTqT/1

For the details of the parameters of Regular Expression Extractor,  see [here](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)

Comment: As you said, I have updated the same, but, the dynamic course id is not extracted. Server generated dynamic course id = 1201 and The extracted course id=1..